# Taking in TextBoxes of the Same Name

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've been taking in an array of textboxes, all of which have the same name. For example, one of them is like this:

`<input type=text name="serial[]">
<input type=text name="serial[]">
<input type=text name="serial[]">
<input type=text name="serial[]">`

Then I'm taking them in like:

$altSerial = $_POST['serial'];

But I keep getting a variable not defined error.

Any tips?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` and see what you really have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with the form. The HTML you posted is correct (or there aren't any obvious problems with it) - and you should get an array in `$_POST['serial']`

Post them  as well, maybe you haven't set `method="POST"`, or a similar issue.